# IntelliSense move lines while I am choosing suggestion with arrow keys

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-assist

IntelliSense move lines while I am choosing suggestion with arrow keys, so when i press enter (or tab) to confirm - it goes crazy and delete half of my code

gif of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AryDG.jpg

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hmm, no, wrong company.  This isn't Microsoft IntelliSense at work.  The icons in the left rail are non-standard.  Disable the extension to get ahead.

Comment: In this case the picture is needed. However the question probably should be a bug report for the software vendor.  I guess the person asking is looking for a work around.